# Selenium Web Driver in IE - Control is passing to childwindow from parent window but unable to locate the elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_JB7nwFYqbxWGNRUG8zZGpOdXc)I am very new to selenium web driver. I am automating an application where after clicking a link, a popup window opens up and the rest of the operations needs to be carried out in the popup window. The issue i am facing is, i am able to navigate to popup window using WindowHandle and as well as the page title of the popup window is also correctly getting captured.But i am unable to locate any of the input web elements in the popup window

code linked above:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
 Dim sheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet2 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet3 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet4 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet5 As Excel.Worksheet

 Dim length As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim text1 As String
 Dim text2 As String
 Dim text3 As String
 Dim text4 As String
 Dim text5 As String
 Dim text6 As String
 Dim input1 As String
 Dim input2 As String
 Dim input3 As String
 Dim output4 As String
 Dim output5 As String
 Dim output6 As String





 Set Sheet5 = Worksheets(5)
 text1 = Sheet5.Cells(4, 2).Value
 text2 = Sheet5.Cells(4, 6).Value
 text3 = Sheet5.Cells(4, 8).Value
 input1 = Sheet5.Cells(10, 2).Value
 input2 = Sheet5.Cells(10, 6).Value
 input3 = Sheet5.Cells(10, 8).Value

  Sheet5.Cells(4, 2).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(4, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(4, 8).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(10, 2).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(10, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(10, 8).Value = ""


  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = ""


 Sheet5.Cells(4, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(4, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(4, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(10, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(10, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 28

 Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6




 Set Sheet3 = Worksheets(3)
 length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet3.Columns(1))

 For i = 1 To length
  text4 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value
  text5 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'text6 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value

  If text1 = text4 And text2 = text5 And text3 Like "?[NB,NS,NF,PE]" Then
    Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 5).Value And Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 6) And Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 4)

  End If
 Next

 For i = 1 To length
  output4 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 5).Value
  output5 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'output6 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value

  If input1 = output4 And input2 = output5 And input3 Like "?[NB,NS,NF,PE]" Then
    Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 6) And Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 4)

  End If
 Next



 'For i = 1 To length
  'text4 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value
  'text5 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'text6 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value
  'If text1 = text2 Then
    'Sheet3.Cells(7, 2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'End If
 'Next

 If Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If text1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If text1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If text1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If input1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If input1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = "provide some value in search text"

End If
If Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If input1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

End Sub



Private Sub Search_Click()
 Dim sheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet2 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet3 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet4 As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim Sheet5 As Excel.Worksheet

 Dim length As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim text1 As String
 Dim text2 As String
 Dim text3 As String
 Dim text4 As String
 Dim text5 As String
 Dim text6 As String
 Dim input1 As String
 Dim input2 As String
 Dim input3 As String
 Dim output4 As String
 Dim output5 As String
 Dim output6 As String





 Set Sheet5 = Worksheets(5)
 text1 = Sheet5.Cells(4, 2).Value
 text2 = Sheet5.Cells(4, 6).Value
 text3 = Sheet5.Cells(4, 8).Value
 input1 = Sheet5.Cells(10, 2).Value
 input2 = Sheet5.Cells(10, 6).Value
 input3 = Sheet5.Cells(10, 8).Value

  Sheet5.Cells(4, 2).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(4, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(4, 8).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(10, 2).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(10, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(10, 8).Value = ""


  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = ""
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = ""


 Sheet5.Cells(4, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(4, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(4, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(10, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 28
 Sheet5.Cells(10, 8).Interior.ColorIndex = 28

 Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6




 Set Sheet3 = Worksheets(3)
 length = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet3.Columns(1))

 For i = 1 To length
  text4 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value
  text5 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'text6 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value

  If text1 = text4 And text2 = text5 And text3 Like "?[NB,NS,NF,PE]" Then
    Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 5).Value And Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 6) And Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 4)

  End If
 Next

 For i = 1 To length
  output4 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 5).Value
  output5 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'output6 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value

  If input1 = output4 And input2 = output5 And input3 Like "?[NB,NS,NF,PE]" Then
    Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value And Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 6) And Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = Sheet3.Cells(i, 4)

  End If
 Next



 'For i = 1 To length
  'text4 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value
  'text5 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'text6 = Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value
  'If text1 = text2 Then
    'Sheet3.Cells(7, 2).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 2).Value
  'End If
 'Next

 If Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If text1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 3).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If text1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 6).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If text1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(7, 9).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If input1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 3).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

If Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If input1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 6).Value = "provide some value in search text"

End If
If Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = "" Then
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = "No result found"
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
 Else
  Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 43
 End If

If input1 = "" Then
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
 Sheet5.Cells(13, 9).Value = "provide some value in search text"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to post the code which is not working.

Comment: i am not able to paste the full code here.

Comment: Use edit question for the same.

Comment: Added the code link in the main question

Comment: @Rajit At which line are you seeing the error? Thanks

Comment: second last line @Dev. when the code is trying to find the element in the child window:driver.findElement(By.id("existCallRef")).click();

Comment: 1. What are you if doing through `driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();` within `if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(window_title))` ?

Comment: 2. What are you if doing through `driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();` within `if(!MainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))` ?

Comment: Sorry , i didnt understood your comment. I am clicking the element for the child window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few words regarding the solution:

1. Keep your `imports` minimal.
2. Refrain from using unwanted imports `import com.thoughtworks.selenium.webdriven.commands.Click;`
3. Review your code & remove unwanted code `driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();`
4. Avoid using `Thread.sleep(6000);`
5. Once you induce `implicitlyWait` its valid throughout your execution.
6. Use css if your xpath looks vulnerable `By.xpath("//Image[@title = 'SEARCH HTTPS']")`
7. Here is your own working code with a few simple tweaks which print `text IM sent` on the console at the end:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\your_directory\\IEDriverServer.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("https://194.74.171.122/e-ServiceDesk/frmLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=/e-ServiceDesk/default.aspx");
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   String window_title1 = driver.getTitle();
   if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(window_title1))
   {
       driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).clear();
       driver.findElement(By.id("txtUserName")).sendKeys("RSen");
       driver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
       Thread.sleep(6000);
   }
   String window_title2 = driver.getTitle();
   if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase(window_title2))
   {
       Boolean a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Image[@title = 'SEARCH HTTPS']")).isDisplayed() ;
       System.out.println(a);
       String MainWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//Image[@title = 'SEARCH HTTPS']")).click();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();
       Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();
       while(i1.hasNext())         
           {       
               String ChildWindow=i1.next();
               if(!MainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))           
               {           
                       driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);        
                       driver.manage().window().maximize();
                       Thread.sleep(10000);
                       String c = driver.getTitle();
                       System.out.println(c);  
                       Thread.sleep(5000);
                       driver.switchTo().frame("eFormContents");
                       Thread.sleep(3000);
                       driver.findElement(By.id("existCallRef")).click();
                       driver.findElement(By.id("existCallRef")).sendKeys("IM");
                       System.out.println("text IM sent");
               }
           }   
   }
   ```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Sorry @Dev , i didnt declined it. I have Voted up for the answer. Not sure if some missed click happened or not.

Comment: i have done that. But again its getting decremented to 0